# Compare Elements in One Array with Two Other Arrays by Position in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array (a_array) and I need to compare each element with the elements in the same position in b_array and c_array, returning the lower of those two values.

```
a_array = [5031 5038 5040]
b_array = [5050 5055 5870]
c_array = [5611 5743 5780]
```

So in the above example:

i. compare 5031 with 5050 and 5611 returning 5050;

ii. compare 5038 with 5055 and 5743 returning 5055;

iii. compare 5040 with 5870 and 5780 returning 5780.

I could use a for loop to do this but is there a vecotorized approach?

Comment: Given your stated answer ([5050,5055,5780]) ... what is the purpose of a_array?

Comment: Fair point, it's the lowest of b and c

Comment: you can use ```zip``` function to the b,c arrays to get min value for the every array position: ```res = [min(i) for i in zip(b,c)]```. It will be: ```[5050, 5055, 5780]```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only care about `b_array`/`c_array`, use [`numpy.minimum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html):

```
np.minimum(b_array, c_array)
```

Output: `array([5050, 5055, 5780])`

If you want to consider all arrays, you can use [`np.minimum.reduce`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html):

```
np.minimum.reduce([a_array, b_array, c_array])
```

Or [`hstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) and [`min`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.min.html):

```
np.vstack([a_array, b_array, c_array]).min(axis=0)
```

Output: `array([5031, 5038, 5040])`